# Setting up Secondary server to take over Primary Server when fail

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have this problem and searched but no answer. 
My primary server is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard edition.
My secondary server is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard edition(Sitting there doing nothing now).
What i want to attain is to use my Win2012R2 as a failover server to take over if my Primary Win2008R2 fail for whatever reason. Mainly targeting for Internet, as all the computers' DNS Server is to my Primary Server IP, Active Directory service and Access DB is in the Primary server. So looking for a secondary server and totally do the job if the primary server fail.

Comment: You should set up your 2012R2 server as primary DC (and other FSMO roles), 2008 R2 is EOL soon. What you are describing is a completely standard AD design, nothing unusual there. What's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

The most of the services from Microsoft can be configured in active-standby and even active-active way. For example, DNS server can be replicated using built-in technologies, same for DHCP, Active Directory. Maybe even building Failover Cluster for high availability and any SDS for its replication?

Answer (score 2):

1) Upgrade to at least WS2016, there’s no point in messing up with ancient and soon to be unsupported tech (WS2008 & 2012).

2) Virtualize! There’s no point in bare metal deployments unless your primary business app vendor is living under the rock and doesn’t support virtualization in 2019 for whatever reason.

3) Configure app and service specific clustering. Say DC replicate on their own, SQL Server has AGs, Exchange got DAG, file servers prefers DFS-R (if you’re fine with notoriously annoying lack of locks, but that’s another story...) and so on.

4) For generic apps use some shared storage and enable HA for VMs.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need some more information about your enviroment. The solution depends on how you have provisioned your servers. I would also recommend to use the same Serverversion.

If you have physical machines with local attached storage you could try to add the other server to role, example for DNS: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc816885(v=ws.10)
Aso Lenniey has suggested, I also would make the newer version to the master. For the fileservices (access) you could create a script which is copying the file to the other server.

If you have virtualized Servers with a iSCSI you could use WSCF for clustering the fileservice or dns. Also in this architecture you can then provision the AD DS roles on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for a "just Failover everything" case within a running (hardware) server. The world would be a much more reliable place, if someone would invent that :-)

So you will have to do one of those things:

- Do a failover configuration for every single service
- Virtualize your machine(s) and configure a hardware failover (like vmware HA)

In case you choose a service native failover, you will have to configure replication/failover for every service, one by one. DNS through DNS replication (primary/secondary or AD integrated - and set the 2nd IP as alternate dns in your clients), AD through a second DC (make sure you have two global catalogs!) and a fileserver through a regular file copy interval (MDB is not readable when beeing written in) or DFS (which I would set up).